# Totally messed up header.php, avada theme

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

I am brand new in wordpress, spent a lot, a lot of time working on this site: www.hupo.hr

I have managed to set it up compeltely, no mistakes, and then, to my sorrow, I have decided to play with google webmasters tools, google analytics, and google tag manager. They all wanted me to enter meta tags into the header. So I googled, and found a few videos with instructions. Installed a few plugins, like all in one SEO, tag manager etc., and finally started playing in Apperances, Editor, theme: Avada, header.php, then started to use a few plugins to insert google analytics tags and google webmasters tools meta tag.

And all of a sudden, the whole website went to scramble. Colours changed, titles got broken, pages started dissapearing, thumbnails got lost.... Horrible experience :)

Is there any chance that someone experienced might help out and look at the header.php - this is the only place in Editor where I have played around, foolishly of
course.

http://pastebin.com/8gAAwzEc

Comment: Reinstall the theme, your changes will be overwritten on the next theme update anyway. Take a look at the WordPress documentation and create a child theme for your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really know what you are doing you shouldn't be editing any of the .php files for wordPress.  That's kind of the point of having a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) you don't need to know what your doing to have a nice website.

Try and change the Theme of your current wordPress site to something different it should if you are lucky over wright any changes you made.

My advice stick to the plugins until you get comfortable with php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear that you lost all your hard work. Starting out with WordPress can be tough. Lots of little details to keep up with, and sometimes folks get very far (like you did) and lose their work, either to updates, or to mistakes while they were setting up their site.

Gerald S was right... it sounds like you probably didn't have a child theme installed. You should install one and make edits in the child theme. You're new, so some resources that will help are http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes and http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

To DalmTo's point, it's risky to play around with PHP unless you know what you're doing... but then again you have to learn somehow and playing around is one of the best ways to do it. Hats off for giving it a shot. Next time, maybe trying using a text editor with FTP instead of making edits in the admin. If you make a mistake (you're new; you will. For that matter, you breath, you will), you can more easily undo that in a text editor with FTP than you can in the editor in the admin. One missing semi colon and you're gonna be using FTP anyway.

Also, it should go without saying, but keep backups of your work. There are several plugins that make this easy. Make sure you take advantage of them.

All in all, you should reinstall the theme. You should redo the customizations in a child theme and make sure you're using the right files, per the template hierarchy. And you should probably stop making edits to PHP in the editor. That's pretty risky. Will you lean on plugins a lot at first? Yep. But after a while it starts to make a lot more sense... and you gotta get in there and play around with things in order for that to happen. If nothing else, hats off for giving it a shot.